# How to split array objects into two(or 2d array) by seperation character

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to split an array like shown below.

```
let arrayToSplit = ["Europe|#|France|#|Paris", "Europe|#|Italy|#|Rome", "America|#|USA|#|Washington", "America|#|Canada|#|Ottawa"]
```

Into

```
let firstArray = ["Europe", "Europe", "America", "America"]
let secondArray = ["France", "Italy", "USA", "Canada"]
let thirdArray = ["Paris", "Rome", "Washington", "Ottawa"]
```

By separating into these three arrays I want to split the data income and present it in a `UITableView`.

Comment: `P.S: If 2d array is [] appropriate` => Depends on what you want to do really.

Comment: I'm just trying to separate bunch of binary values stored in same array object. The next thing I'm gonna do is present these values in a TableView as one title, the other subtitle.

Comment: Then an array of dictionaries (or array of custom objects) may be a good solution for a `UITableView` data source.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! But what I'm gonna if I want to separate three values? Dictionaries are binomial. @Larme

Comment: I don't speak Swift, I can do it in Objective-C, and try to translate it, but I would miss some Swift "specialties". Please edit your question saying what you want to do with the result.

Comment: something like this ? arrayToSplit.flatMap{ $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|").first }
arrayToSplit.flatMap{ $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|").last }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but with the expected result (hints are in the code comments):

```
let arrayToSplit = ["Europe|#|France|#|Paris", "Europe|#|Italy|#|Rome", "America|#|USA|#|Washington", "America|#|Canada|#|Ottawa"]
var firstArray = [String]()
var secondArray = [String]()
var thirdArray = [String]()

for element in arrayToSplit {

    // new array with substrings divided by "|#|" e.g. ["Europe", "Europe", "America", "America"]
    let newArray = element.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|")
    firstArray.append(newArray[0])
    secondArray.append(newArray[1])
    thirdArray.append(newArray[2])
}

print("first array: \(firstArray)") // first array: ["Europe", "Europe", "America", "America"]
print("second array: \(secondArray)") // second array: ["France", "Italy", "USA", "Canada"]
print("third array: \(thirdArray)") // third array: ["Paris", "Rome", "Washington", "Ottawa"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let arrayToSplit = ["Europe|#|France|#|Paris", "Europe|#|Italy|#|Rome", "America|#|USA|#|Washington", "America|#|Canada|#|Ottawa"]


    print(arrayToSplit)


    let firstArray : NSMutableArray = []
    let secondArray : NSMutableArray = []
    let thirdArray : NSMutableArray = []

    for var i = 0; i < arrayToSplit.count; i++
    {
        let str : String = arrayToSplit[i] as String

         let ary = str.characters.split{$0 == "|"}.map(String.init)

        firstArray.addObject(ary[0])
        secondArray.addObject(ary[2])
        thirdArray.addObject(ary[4])
    }

    print(firstArray)
    print(secondArray)
    print(thirdArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrayToSplit = ["Europe|#|France|#|Paris", "Europe|#|Italy|#|Rome", "America|#|USA|#|Washington", "America|#|Canada|#|Ottawa"]

let arrayOfLists = arrayToSplit.map{
    $0.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|")
}

let columns = Array(0..<3).map{ i in
    arrayOfLists.map{ list in list[i]}
}

print(columns)
//[["Europe", "Europe", "America", "America"], ["France", "Italy", "USA", "Canada"], ["Paris", "Rome", "Washington", "Ottawa"]]
```

Comment: Good one. very compact.