# How to delete part of string indicated after a character?

Tags: swift, string

This is what I need.

var str = "This is an |#|example text!"

After deleting:

str = "This is an "

Comment: Find the range of `|` or `|#|`, and delete then?

Comment: That's it. Then update the string.

Comment: `substringWithRange()`, `substringFromIndex()`, `substringToIndex()`?

Comment: You already know the answer since you've accepted [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38477381/2227743) and the solution is clearly shown in it...

Comment: You're right @EricD, it escaped from my mind while asking. Sorry. :/

Comment: @ardakaraca Eh, it happens. Don't worry too much about this downvoted question. Just try the [rubber duck strategy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) next time before asking. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

`var subdividedStringArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString("|#|")`

now you have an array with 2 strings, you can access the first one with:

`str = subdividedStringArray[0]`

or:

`str = subdividedStringArray.first`